# Glob recursive/zero or more directories, excluding directories

Tags: node.js, glob

I am using the [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) package to work with some files. My directory tree looks something like this:

```
root
|   file1
|   file2
|   
+---folder1
|       file3
|       file4
|   
+---folder2
|       file5
|       file6
|       
\---folder3
        file7
        file8
```

I want to get all the files (including those at the root) except for those in `folder1`. I could filter the array returned after calling the glob function, but I'm hoping to avoid having to retrieve them at all. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're currently using `**/*` for all files, I'd probably use [`glob-all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-all) and specify some paths to exclude.

```
globAll.sync([
    '**/*',
    '!folder1/**/*'
])
```

Comment: Is it possible to exclude all node_modules no matter how deep they are like that? I gave a try but it was not successful

Comment: @Maxime Please ask a new question, rather than leaving a comment on an existing answer.